# Are all Lightning to USB-C cables capable of the same charging power?

Tags: usb, charging, lightning

My iPhone came with a Lightning to USB-C cable which looks similar to the cable that I got with my Apple Magic Keyboard and Apple Magic Mouse.

Are all of these cables capable of the high-speed charging of my iPhone, or do I need to be careful not to mix these cables up?

Comment: For the purposes you're using them for (charging your phone), almost certainly, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [8 pin Lightning connector and assorted Apple cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_(connector)) will not be the limiting factor for charging any Apple device. The power adapter to which it connects will determine the fastest charging rate since the [MFI program](https://mfi.apple.com/en/home) has [certified manufacturers](https://mfi.apple.com/authorized-manufacturers) to ensure correct fast charging with embedded chips in the cables to identify them to the iPhone / iPad / keyboard or other accessory that charges via lightning connector.

[image: third party cable with MFI lightning connector]

Most third party cables ([especially ones that are listed](https://mfi.apple.com/account/accessory-search)) will be just as good for charging - especially ones with MFI hardware and certification. Examine the connector with a magnifying device and the Apple ones have clean flat contacts and even side dimples for a snug fit.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204566

Comment: MFi link goes nowhere. This one works: https://mfi.apple.com/en/home.html

Comment: Yes, you have to be signed in to get there - not a direct link. Thanks for the check and note @IconDaemon